# Etale covers of products of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

Is a finite etale cover of a product of curves again a product of curves?

The answer is no in general. Here's one way to construct an example. Take the product $A$ of two elliptic curves and an isogeny $J\to A$ with $J$ the Jacobian of some genus two curve.

How can we get easy  counterexamples like this in the case of the product of two higher genus curves?

Answer (score 7):

Let $C_i \rightarrow C_i/G = C'_i$ ($i=1,2$) be finite unramified covers of degree 
$|G|>1$ of curves $C'_i$ each of genus at least $2$.  Then the quotient of
$C_1 \times C_2$ by the diagonal action of $G$ is an unramified cover of
$C'_1 \times C'_2$.

Comment: For completeness, one needs to show that the unramified cover is not itself a product of curves. If, for instance, $C_1'$ and $C'_2$ have the same genus and $|G|=2$, this can be seen by computing $h^1(\mathcal O)$ and $h^2(\mathcal O)$.